# Preprocessor directives when using Visual Studio 2019 CMake project not visible in editor

Tags: visual-studio, cmake, cross-platform, visual-studio-2019, conditional-compilation

I'm experimenting with the CMake project type in Visual Studio 2019 for the first time (no real prior experience with CMake). I wanted to compile a very simple piece of code and run it on both Windows and Linux (using WSL or my MX Linux VM).

I have three configurations defined in the CMake JSON (x64-Debug, WSL-Debug and Linux-Clang-Debug). I wanted to test some conditional compilations to drive different behavior on Linux vs Windows, so I added a #if defined(_WIN32) || defined(_WIN64) and a #if defined(LINUX) || defined(UNIX).

In the editor for my .c file, the _WIN64 is always defined, even if I'm using the WSL-Debug config or the Linux-Clang-Debug config.

In the JSON config, there's options for "CMake command arguments" and "Build command arguments", but neither of those seem to take a "-DLINUX" or something equivalent (I get errors).

Where would I define these preprocessor directives so I can:
1) have -DLINUX or _DUNIX for my WSL\Linux configs, and not _WIN32 or _WIN64

2) have _WIN32 or _WIN64 for my Window configs

3) and see these take effect in real-time in the editor, so the code for that config is not "compiled" out (like it would if I was using a normal VS build project and swapped between configurations with different preprocessor directives, which handles this scenario just fine)

Comment: I'm interested in this too, did you make any progress?